# Importing newer projects into older versions of Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, version, assets

I'm creating a small gameworld for school in Unity. It needs a city n' stuff, so we can use the worlds in VR. The school has computers with an older version of Unity, and respectively, models from the Asset Store that are compatible with that version and below. Contrastly, my computer has the latest version of Unity and all the Asset Store assets available to me.

Question is, if I use newer assets in my world, then import the project to an older version of Unity, will there be and major issues with the assets? Or will those assets just simply refuse to port?

Comment: You'll likely run into major issues importing entire projects into older versions. It's hard to say without explicitly trying it, and the issues may not be immediately obvious. For the most part, models should be pretty safe

Comment: As @Mikedg said it's hard to predict what might go wrong. Upgrading a lower version project to newer version can be done however if you are downgrading the project from higher version to lower version then it could result in some errors again based on version you try and type of assets also.So I recommend you to install multiple version of unity in your system.Since Unity latest version and Unity Hub allows you to maintain multiple versions on same device it could be better

Comment: Your question is, can you run the builded asset in new version in the old version?

Comment: Anything containing scripts might break. Reason the Unity API provides information on how scripts have to be modified while migrating to a newer version. However how should an old version know how to handle code from the newer API? -> It is impossible to downgrade automatically! However if it is primarily about 3D models then there should be no problem. In general you should use the same Unity Version for development everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the package. I would say you're going in the more difficult direction, as Unity does pretty well with being able to integrate deprecated packages into newer versions of Unity, but not as well with bringing newer assets into older versions of Unity.

I would suspect things like simple models would be fine, but if you try anything that dives more deeply into scripting/animation/lighting (I know I've had trouble with Text Mesh Pro going in both directions), you might run into some difficulties.

I would download the matching version of Unity and work within that to be on the safe side and avoid integration issues entirely.